# Isolation Forest: Combining Input Features with Output Y

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

Seems to me that when you have a data-set with outliers, those outliers might be caused by not only the features, but by output variable as well.

So for anomaly detection in your training set, why does every example i see on the internet NOT include features appended with output variable?

Comment: What do you mean by output? Labeled data, ie some target variable? Is it the target of your anomaly detector or target of another model?

Answer (score 1):

actually you can approach an anomaly like that, but there are some problems outliers are varied in features that may cause a lot of problems here and most of the advanced anomaly models are the online trainer so it may cause a lot of afford to do this
your model will be too much complicated
I draw an example for you
[image: borderlines: blue one is anomaly and orange is your approach, i know my drawing sucks and it must be straight lines:) sry]